# Retry zuul request with new Auth header for 401 status code

Tags: java, spring-boot, http-proxy, netflix-zuul, spring-retry

I need to catch '401' Un-Authorized status code of the zuul requests and retry using a new Access token

I am using spring-cloud-starter-zuul for routing the requests, I am adding the Access token in PreRequestFilter from Spring Session..
I need to catch the '401' Un-Authorized status code for the expired tokens and retry the same request using a new access token created using the existing token..

I have looked at this [link](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_retrying-failed-requests.html) on configuring the retry option on zuul for specific status codes, but could not found any reference where i could modify the headers and retry

Here is my zuul configuration..

```
zuul.routes.service1-api.url=http://service1:8080/api/v1/

zuul.routes.service2-api.url=http://service2:8080/api/v1/

zuul.routes.service3-api.url=http://service3:8080/api/v1/

zuul.host.connect-timeout-millis=60000
zuul.host.socket-timeout-millis=60000
zuul.add-proxy-headers=false
ribbon.eureka.enabled=false
```

In my PreRequestFilter

```
 @Override   
    public Object run() {
        this.setHeadersToContext(ctx);
        return null;
    }
```